# how to change language of firefox?

Tags: firefox

Is there any way to customize firefox in my own language 
I downloaded source code of firefox but could not find how to do this?
*Firefox is not available in my local language

As far as i kno firefox is open source so we can do this*

Comment: Here is a list of teams working on localization for Mozilla https://wiki.mozilla.org/L10n:Teams and a page on how to contribute https://wiki.mozilla.org/L10n:Contribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this, hope it can help you in the right direction:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Creating_a_Language_Pack